# Pagination in plugin's backend

Tags: php, pagination, admin-menu, add-menu-page

I am displaying a list of posts in the plugin backend but I can't seem to get the pagination to work. I used the standard approach of getting the "paged" variable and then passing it to `get_posts()`'s arguments, but whenever I visit my custom backend page or subpage and add the `&page=2` variable I get that permissions error about not having enough of them to visit that page.

*Is there a special way to apply pagination in the backend?*

Comment: What context are you doing this in? Is it on a post edit page? Options page? Generic admin page?

Comment: @TomJNowell Custom submenu page added with add_submenu_page whose parent is a custom page added with add_menu_page.

Answer (score 0):

In the admin back-end of a plugin, you can't use the query_vars hook and the get_query_var built in function since the page itself is a query parameter. To get around this, I simply add a new query parameter to the end of your plugin page link called, '&pagenum=#" and I pull it out manually using:

```
$pagenum = isset( $_GET['pagenum'] ) ? absint( $_GET['pagenum'] ) : 1;
```

There might be a better way of doing this, but I haven't found one that requires less effort.

Here is what the plugin url might look like:

```
admin.php?page=[plugin-dir]%2F[plugin-slug].php&pagenum=1
```